# Specifying 'older than' in a DELETE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that I would like to use to delete rows of data with a 'viewed' column datetime value older than 24 hours. How can I do this with one query? Is it possible?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$delete_expired_notifications_query= "DELETE FROM notifications WHERE user_id= 
'".$u_id."' AND viewed (some code that says older than 24hrs)";
    mysqli_query($connect, $delete_expired_notifications_query);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `viewed` is a MySQL temporal type (which it *should* be):

```sql
... AND viewed < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Comment: it should be older than 24 hours, so `viwed > Now() - 24 hour` :)

Comment: @bonCodigo: No, records that have been viewed *after* 24 hours less than now would be *newer* than...

Comment: Got it, viewed older than 24 hours (not within now and the 24 hours) cool ;) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

with [date_Add](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) and interval you can try this for records older than 24 hours from now..

```
DELETE FROM notifications WHERE user_id= 
'".$u_id."' AND viewed < date_Add(now(), interval - 24 hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM notifications WHERE user_id = '".$u_id."' 
      AND viewed < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)";
```

or

```
DELETE FROM notifications WHERE user_id = '".$u_id."' 
      AND viewed < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -24 HOUR)";
```